# How to make cross compile development enviroment that can use shared libraries from Pi?

Tags: linux, cross-compilation

I was able to install [toolchain](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) and compile programs that use basic c libs. But that is not really useful when compiling big programs.

I've learned that, when cross compiling, compiler will look for libraries that are installed it toolchain directory and in the beginning there are only few basic.

So, to build something with more dependencies one should take a list of all and compile one-by-one to finally install wanted program. That could take ages and there is high probability that something can go wrong.

So, my question is: If there are already-compiled libraries in Arch or Raspian for Pi, how can one use them instead of compiling every package by hand? Is there any way to copy required to toolchain or wherever cross compiler looks for libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I made it by mounting Raspi SD card to

```
/path/to/toolchain/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/
```

I use `gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf` compiler, as it is suggested one.

I don't know if that is good or bad way (maybe someone knows better) but that is the way I did it and it worked.